# I'm switching sever hosts in minecraft but dont want to lose the progress from my current server, is it possible to move my world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting

The site I use to run my current server doesn't allow me to use mods, so I planned on switching to a new site like Apex Hosting, but I don't want to lose my server and have to start over. Would it be possible for me to move my world from that server to a new server?

Comment: that would depend on the host. if you have access to the files yes, if you dont then no

Comment: If you are using a hosting platform like Aternos then the only filesystem you would be able to interact with is your world folder, and that's it. All other files are not accessible by the end user. Realistically, if you can download your world folder from the host, then migration should be easy enough.

Comment: If you're still confused by these comments/don't know just tell us what host you're using! I bet someone who knows about that one could better help you then

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, most server hosts should allow you to access your server files, from there just copy all the important files like permissions, the world file, the data file, etc, and move it to your new server, but if you are going to be using mods you might just want to restart as most mods use world gen, so I think if your going to use mods, just restart, or only keep the player data file, which should save all of the items you have in your inventory.